# logstash IllegalStateException?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, bigdata, logstash

I am trying to execute this command: `aymenstien@aymenstien-VPCEH2Q1E:/usr/share/logstash$ ./bin/logstash -f /home/aymenstien/Bureau/fb.conf`

here is the config file:

```
input { file { path => "/home/aymenstien/Bureau/mydoc/*" start_position => beginning codec => json sincedb_path => "/home/aymenstien/Bureau/mydoc/postj1.sincedb" } } output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } elasticsearch { hosts => "localhost:9200"; index => "fbpost" document_type => "post" timeout => 30 workers => 1 } }
```

I am getting this error:

> aymenstien@aymenstien-VPCEH2Q1E:/usr/share/logstash$ ./bin/logstash -f
>   /home/aymenstien/Bureau/fb.conf  WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml
>   which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You
>   can specify the path using --path.settings. Continuing using the
>   defaults Could not find log4j2 configuration at path
>   /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties. Using default config
>   which logs errors to the console [FATAL] 2018-07-05 12:47:56.496
>   [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred!
>   {:error=>#,
>   :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:448:in
>   `validate'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:230:in`
>   validate_value'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:141:in
>   `block in validate_all'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in`each'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:140:in
>   `validate_all'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:279:in`
>   execute'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in
>   `run'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:238:in`
>   run'",
>   "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in
>   `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:73:in`
>   '"]} [ERROR] 2018-07-05 12:47:56.554 [main] Logstash -
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because
>   of an error: (SystemExit) exit

Comment: input {
     file {
 path => "/home/aymenstien/Bureau/mydoc/*"
 start_position => beginning
 codec => json
 sincedb_path => "/home/aymenstien/Bureau/mydoc/postj1.sincedb"
 }
}

output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 elasticsearch {  
  hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
  index => "fbpost"
  document_type => "post"
  timeout => 30
  workers => 1
 }
}

Comment: Please edit the post to make the config file legible--use indentation etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using --path.settings /usr/share/logstash/config along with the config file.

*The issue is that logstash is not able to find the settings directory(Config folder ) path.*

Updated command:
./bin/logstash -f /home/aymenstien/Bureau/fb.conf --path.settings /usr/share/logstash/config